# After using the scripts argument to setup.py, where do I find my scripts?

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py

After running setup.py, where do I find the scripts?  The documentation just says,

> [When we install the package, setuptools will copy the script to our PATH and make it available for general use.](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-scripts-keyword-argument)

```
cd /Users/me
python3 -m venv my_test
/Users/me/my_test/bin/pip3 install ~/test
ls /Users/me/my_test/bin

>>> python3 pip3 pip3.8
```

Sample test/setup.py:

```
from   setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='test',
      packages=find_packages(),
      scripts=['test/tester',],
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False)
```

I've been packaging my Python scripts using setup.py for years, but I've never been able to figure out how to use the 'scripts' option.

Python 3.8 macOS 10.15

Answer (score 2):

They go here [(docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html#installation-paths):

```
import sysconfig
sysconfig.get_path("scripts")
```

The exact location on filesystem is platform-dependent, and it can also be influenced by some other factors such as whether you are using a virtual environment, or have requested installed to the user site (`pip install --user`).

Comment: Thank you Wim!  This is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

The short and broad answer is, they get put somewhere in PATH.

To find them on *nix, try either of:

```sh
$ command -v tester
$ which tester
```

(Windows: try `where`.)

If you are working in a virtual environment created through [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html),  they will get put (on *nix) in `venv/bin/`. For example, after installing Ansible, a handful of executables will be put there:

```sh
$ ls -1 venv/bin | grep ansible
ansible
ansible-config
ansible-connection
ansible-console
ansible-doc
...
```